# REST Handling of Removed Backwards-compatible Functionality

Tags: api, rest, versioning, semantic-versioning

How does [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/) define the version change required when functionality is removed but the client will not necessarily break?

For example, if I have a resource that accepts a sort param:

```
/person?sort=name
```

If I removed the ability to sort, the existing clients could still consume the service (sort just would not be honored). **Does SemVer consider this a backwards incompatible change?** **If not, what rule specifically addresses this situation?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my perspective existing clients will break - they expect for the result set to be returned in a sorted fashion and it won't be. That means that, quite likely, some web page or app-screen somewhere will display data in a non-sorted fashion even though the user clicked a button asking for stuff to be sorted by name. The client's user experience changes negatively and unexpectedly, even though the application doesn't fall over. As such, you're talking about a breaking-change and so a major version increase.

If you could be absolutely sure that no client *used* the API element then it *might* be a different thing - e.g. *if* you work in a closed world where you can inspect and verify all your clients then you might choose to pretend that the API element never existed and only consider the change a minor or patch change. But 99% of the time it should be a version increase and even in the closed-world situation I'd think that would be an extreme approach that would only be justified in certain circumstances.